# Two Dim Array, Multiple roles for user! Roles in own columns

Tags: eclipse-scout

I am using eclipse scout! Now I want to list all users! Thats fine, but my db structure is like this:

```
+----+--------+-----------+---------------+-----------+--------+----------+
| ID |  Name  |  Surname  | Administrator | Moderator | Editor | Operator |
+----+--------+-----------+---------------+-----------+--------+----------+
|  1 | myname | mysurname |             1 |         1 |      0 |        0 |
+----+--------+-----------+---------------+-----------+--------+----------+
```

So, when I populate the table, I need to show all roles of single user! For example: If user "test" has roles of administrator, moderator, table row has to be like this:

```
╔════╦═════════════╦══════════╦══════════════════════════╗
║ ID ║ Usernameame ║ Password ║          Roles           ║
╠════╬═════════════╬══════════╬══════════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ test        ║ test     ║ administrator, moderator ║
╚════╩═════════════╩══════════╩══════════════════════════╝
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have different possibility of doing this. One possibility is to do it on the client side; this is the solution I will describe here:

Create a table containing those rows:

- ID: long column
- Name: String column
- Surname: String column
- Administrator: Boolean column (not displayable)
- Moderator: Boolean column (not displayable)
- Editor: Boolean column (not displayable)
- Operator: Boolean column (not displayable)
- Roles: String column, Ignored from the Table Data (in the formData or in the TablePageData)

In this example, the table is in a TableField, but it works exactly the same for a TablePage.

```
@Order(10.0)
@FormData(sdkCommand = FormData.SdkCommand.USE, value = AbstractTableFieldBeanData.class, defaultSubtypeSdkCommand = FormData.DefaultSubtypeSdkCommand.CREATE)
public class PersonsTableField extends AbstractTableField<PersonsTableField.Table> {

  @Override
  protected int getConfiguredGridH() {
    return 5;
  }

  @Override
  protected int getConfiguredGridW() {
    return 2;
  }

  @Override
  protected String getConfiguredLabel() {
    return TEXTS.get("Persons");
  }

  @Order(10.0)
  public class Table extends AbstractExtensibleTable {

    public NameColumn getNameColumn() {
      return getColumnSet().getColumnByClass(NameColumn.class);
    }

    public SurnameColumn getSurnameColumn() {
      return getColumnSet().getColumnByClass(SurnameColumn.class);
    }

    public ModeratorColumn getModeratorColumn() {
      return getColumnSet().getColumnByClass(ModeratorColumn.class);
    }

    public EditorColumn getEditorColumn() {
      return getColumnSet().getColumnByClass(EditorColumn.class);
    }

    public OperatorColumn getOperatorColumn() {
      return getColumnSet().getColumnByClass(OperatorColumn.class);
    }

    public RolesColumn getRolesColumn() {
      return getColumnSet().getColumnByClass(RolesColumn.class);
    }

    public AdministratorColumn getAdministratorColumn() {
      return getColumnSet().getColumnByClass(AdministratorColumn.class);
    }

    public IdColumn getIdColumn() {
      return getColumnSet().getColumnByClass(IdColumn.class);
    }

    @Order(10.0)
    public class IdColumn extends AbstractLongColumn {

      @Override
      protected String getConfiguredHeaderText() {
        return TEXTS.get("id");
      }
    }

    @Order(20.0)
    public class NameColumn extends AbstractStringColumn {

      @Override
      protected String getConfiguredHeaderText() {
        return TEXTS.get("Name");
      }
    }

    @Order(30.0)
    public class SurnameColumn extends AbstractStringColumn {

      @Override
      protected String getConfiguredHeaderText() {
        return TEXTS.get("Surname");
      }
    }

    @Order(40.0)
    public class AdministratorColumn extends AbstractBooleanColumn {

      @Override
      protected boolean getConfiguredDisplayable() {
        return false;
      }
    }

    @Order(50.0)
    public class ModeratorColumn extends AbstractBooleanColumn {
      @Override
      protected boolean getConfiguredDisplayable() {
        return false;
      }
    }

    @Order(60.0)
    public class EditorColumn extends AbstractBooleanColumn {
      @Override
      protected boolean getConfiguredDisplayable() {
        return false;
      }
    }

    @Order(70.0)
    public class OperatorColumn extends AbstractBooleanColumn {
      @Override
      protected boolean getConfiguredDisplayable() {
        return false;
      }
    }

    @Order(80.0)
    @ColumnData(SdkColumnCommand.IGNORE)
    public class RolesColumn extends AbstractStringColumn {

      @Override
      protected String getConfiguredHeaderText() {
        return TEXTS.get("Roles");
      }

      @Override
      protected void execDecorateCell(Cell cell, ITableRow row) throws ProcessingException {
        cell.setText(StringUtility.join(", ",
            BooleanUtility.nvl(getAdministratorColumn().getValue(row)) ? TEXTS.get("Administrator") : null,
            BooleanUtility.nvl(getModeratorColumn().getValue(row)) ? TEXTS.get("Moderator") : null,
            BooleanUtility.nvl(getEditorColumn().getValue(row)) ? TEXTS.get("Editor") : null,
            BooleanUtility.nvl(getOperatorColumn().getValue(row)) ? TEXTS.get("Operator") : null
            ));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice the implementation of `execDecorateCell` in the `RolesColumn`. The text is computed depending the values contained in the invisible columns. Notice also the `ColumnData` annotation on top of this column.

The 4 invisible columns have the property `Displayable` set to `false`.

On the server, if you want to put some data, you can do it like this:

```
PersonsTable tableData = formData.getPersonsTable();
PersonsTableRowData rowData = tableData.addRow();
rowData.setId(42L);
rowData.setName("John");
rowData.setSurname("Johnny");
rowData.setAdministrator(Boolean.TRUE);
rowData.setModerator(Boolean.TRUE);
rowData.setEditor(Boolean.FALSE);
rowData.setOperator(Boolean.FALSE);
```

Notice that there is no `rowData.setRoles(String)` or `rowData.getRoles()` because of the `@ColumnData(SdkColumnCommand.IGNORE)` in the client.

Of course I think you want to use an SQL statement to do it. You will end with something like this:

```
SQL.selectInto("SELECT " +
    " id, " +
    " name, " +
    " surname, " +
    " administrator, " +
    " moderator, " +
    " editor, " +
    " operator " +
    " FROM persons " +
    " INTO " +
    " :{personsTable.id}, " +
    " :{personsTable.name}, " +
    " :{personsTable.surname}, " +
    " :{personsTable.administrator}, " +
    " :{personsTable.moderator}, " +
    " :{personsTable.editor}, " +
    " :{personsTable.operator}",
    formData);
```

Here is my result:

[image: MyForm example - Eclipse Scout]